# if c++ stringstream can convert strings like "0x123" to int?

Tags: c++, stream, hex

I try like below:

```
int main() {    
    string s1 = "0x123";
    int c;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << s1;
    ss >> c;
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

and the output c is 0, seems it doesn't support strings with "0x"

Answer (score 2):

with [`std::hex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) manipulator:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "0x123";
    int c;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << s1;
    ss >> std::hex >> c;
    std::cout << c << std::endl; // 291
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/373b934136b7c2d4)

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this would be to use the **hex manipulator** as shown below:

```
int main() {    
    string s1 = "0x123";
    int c;
    istringstream ss(s1);
   
    ss >> std::hex >> c;//use the hex manipulator
    cout << c << endl;//prints 291 which is the decimal equivalent of hexadecimal 123
}
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/xeKmlAGla).